# Scanning Only the First Character in C

Tags: c, char

I know that adding a space in front of %c in scanf() will scan my second character; however, if two letters were inputted in the first character, it will input the second letter into the second character. How do I scan a single character only?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char firstch, secondch;

printf("Enter your first character: "); 
scanf("%c", &firstch);

printf("Enter your second character: "); 
scanf(" %c", &secondch);

printf("\n Fisrt character : %c \n Second character : %c \n", firstch, secondch);

return 0; 
}
```

This is my result after running:

Enter your first character: ab
Enter your second character:
First character : a
Second character : b

I only want to read the first character 'a', but the second letter 'b' was inputted right away before I enter my second character.

Comment: Try this `scanf("%c%*[^\n]", &firstch);`

Comment: Or obtain each input with `fgets` and exmine a string.

Comment: Or, since you only want to get one character, use `getchar`, which is designed for getting one character.

Comment: scanf("%c%*[^\n]", &firstch); worked!! How did the code work? @Eraklon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a space before the %c will skip whitespace before scanning the next non-whitespace character.  %c itself just scans a single character -- the next character in the input after whatever else was scanned or skipped previously.

So the question is, what do you want to do?  Do you want to skip over all extraneous input on the line after the first character (up to newline?)  `fgets` or `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%c");` will do that (but be careful -- if `firstch` was itself a newline, this will skip the *next* line.)  Do you want to check the input and make sure it is exactly one character on a line?  If so, use `fgets` (not scanf) and check that the line read is exactly two characters (a character and a newline).  Or perhaps you really want to read keystrokes without having the user hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after esch one?  That requires changing the input source setup, which is OS dependent.

Comment: scanf("%c%*[^\n]", &firstch); and scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &secondch); worked out perfectly for scanning a character. May you explain how did the "%c%*[^\n]" work?

Comment: `'*'` is an *assignment suppression* with `scanf`. It tells `scanf` to read and discard all characters matching the *conversion specifier* (e.g. `%[^\n]` -- all characters not including the `'\n'`) without assigning the characters to a parameter. Better, simply use an array and `fgets()`, e.g. `char buf[1024];` then `if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) firstchar = *buf;` Same for `secondchar`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading a line of user-input, use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. That way the entire line of input is read at once and you can simply take the first character from the line. Say you read a line into the array used as buffer called `buf`, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to read each line into */
```

You can simply access the first character as `buf[0]`, or since `buf[0]` is equivalent to `*(but + 0)` in pointer notation, you can simply use `*buf` to get the first character.

As a benefit, since all *line-oriented* functions read and include the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the input, you can simply check if the first character is `'\n'` as a way of indicating end-of-input. The user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone as input to indicate they are done.

Using a *line-oriented* approach is the recommended way to take user input because it consumes and entire line of input each time and what remains in `stdin` unread doesn't depend on the `scanf` conversion specifier or whether a *matching failure* occurs.

Using `" %c%*[^\n]"` is not a fix-all. It leaves the `'\n'` in `stdin` unread. That's why you need the space before `" %c"`. Where it is insidious is if your next input uses a line-oriented function after your code reading characters is done. Unless you manually empty the `'\n'` from `stdin`, before your next attempted line-oriented input, that input will fail because it will see the `'\n'` as the first character remaining in `stdin`.

A short example using `fgets()` for a line-oriented approach would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to read each line into */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually */
        fputs ("enter char: ", stdout);         /* prompt for input */
        /* read/validate line, break on EOF or [Enter] alone */
        if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin) || *buf == '\n')
            break;
        printf ("       got: %c\n\n", *buf);    /* output character read */
    }
}
```

Where you simply take input continually isolating the first character as the value you want until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone to break the read-loop.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgetschar
enter char: a
       got: a

enter char: ab
       got: a

enter char: a whole lot of stuff you don't have to deal with using fgets()
       got: a

enter char: banannas
       got: b

enter char: cantelopes
       got: c

enter char:
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'm still new to C coding, but I have learned something new from you!! Thanks for helping!

Comment: You are welcome. If I can learn something new each day -- it's been a good day! Learning C isn't a race, it's more of a journey, enjoy it. It's not something your will complete in a semester, a year (or really forever -- there is that much there and they tweak the standard from time to time). Approach it the same way you would eat a whale -- one byte at a time `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to C coding, and I've found a suitable answer to my problem by using `scanf("%*[^\n]");`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char firstch, secondch;    

printf("Enter your first character: "); 
scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &firstch);

printf("Enter your second character: "); 
scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &secondch);

printf("\n First character : %c \n Second character : %c \n", firstch, 
secondch);

return 0; 
}
```

Results after running:

Enter your first character: ab
Enter your second character: c

First character : a
Second character : c

Thanks to @Eraklon @Chris Dodd @David C. Rankin

Comment: Try entering only `"\n"` as part of "Enter your first character: "  and see what happens.  This answer works for many cases.  Not well for all.

Comment: Thanks for telling me @chux - Reinstate Monica!! I've just fixed `scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &firstch);` by adding a space before %c

Comment: The post did not specify what happens when an input line only consists of `"\n"`.  This answer obliges the user to re-enter again and again with no prompting if only `"\n"` entered until some non-white-space entered.  Use of `fgets()` in  [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60897628/2410359) can recognize the problem.  As with any code handling user input, many edge cases need consideration.

Comment: I recommend to use `fgets()`. Do not use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.